# Phonegap Xcode 6.1 nsexception

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am tired of looking everywhere to find and answer. I'm new to phonegap and what I just did was creating a default project, building it and then opening with Xcode in order to emulate it.

It runs well, but after a moment throws an error (or exception don't know how it's called) and what it does is just showing the image but not the text and else.

Here is the error:

```
2014-12-12 20:34:39.339 Hello World[4441:609951] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/pas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50XXXXX-BEA1-447C-A70E-98XXXXXXXXA/data/Containers/Data/Application/DFXXXXX-E46C-430D-9B57-9XXXXXXX441/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2014-12-12 20:34:39.606 Hello World[4441:609951] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7ae1a170> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x002ea946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0243aa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x002ea561 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x020c210e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)      setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0201e138 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
    5   Foundation                          0x0201e0bd -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x020539a6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386
    7   UIKit                               0x009d3649 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02450724 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x002245dc -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 316
    10  UIKit                               0x009d210a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1775
    11  UIKit                               0x009d3fa9 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 180
    12  UIKit                               0x0069ce1b -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    13  UIKit                               0x0069d134 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    14  UIKit                               0x0069badf -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1337
    15  UIKit                               0x006b47d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    16  UIKit                               0x0069a81f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x02fba9de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x02fba46f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x02fcc425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0020e1c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00203ad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0020392b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00202bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x002029fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  UIKit                               0x0069a1e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    26  UIKit                               0x0069d8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    27  Hello World                         0x000dbfec main + 92
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02b1aac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And here is the piece of code from where the error comes:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help this is driving me mad.
Regards

PS: how is it possible that I can only include code by indenting with 4 spaces I had to do this for every line, that is so impractical

Comment: For you PS, you can also select your code and hit the {} above the edit box to format the block as code.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird haha alright thanks.. I was doing it line by line like a stupid

Answer (score 5):

I had the same exact issue. The cause of the problem is the **Main Interface** field in your General Settings. This field should be blank. Do not select `MainViewController`, otherwise this error will be thrown.

Here is my example of the error:
[image]

Comment: this answer solved my problem with my Phonegap project! thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I'm going to post it here just in case someone has the same struggle.
What I did was installing cordova, ('npm install -g cordova'). Phonegap installs it (I think) but when trying to execute it in terminal doesn't appear to be installed that's why I did that..